# Is this a normal distribution?

Tags: probability-theory

Given $Z\sim N(0,1)$, a coin is flipped.
Another random variable
$$
W = \begin{cases} \phantom{-}Z & \text{if heads}, \\
-Z & \text{if tails}.
\end{cases}
$$

Is $W$ normal?

I just am not really sure how to start this problem, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The votes to close this question are ill advised, to say the least.

Comment: Assume $Z$ and the behaviour of the coin are independent. If you want to calculate, we find the cdf of $W$, that is, $\Pr(W\le w)$. We can have $W\le w$ in two ways, head and $Z\le w$ or tail and $-Z\le w$, that is, $Z\ge -w$. Continue.

Comment: Alternatively, compute the moment generating function $E[e^{sW}]$.

Comment: At the very least the poser should make a grammatical question.  "...a coin is flipped Another RV" makes little sense.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork : You stopped before the end of the sentence.  It says "Another RV${}\ {}$ $W=\cdots$." Not great style, but perfectly comprehensible. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @RobertIsrael : One drawback of your suggestion is that it has to rely on a proposition whose proof is a bit involved: a distribution whose m.g.f. is the same as that of the normal distribution must be that same distribution: the normal distribution. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy:  I read and re-read the problem statement.  The central awkwardness with the problem statement arise from:  1) The initial "Given" (which is not used in a mathematical sense)... there is nothing about Z that affects the flipping of a coin.  2) The second sentence is not even grammatical (an '=' does not function grammatically as a verb).  3) The last sentence is ungrammatical (viz., a run-on).  The whole problem statement can be improved significantly.

Comment: I read the original version of it just once and understood it immediately.

Comment: "Suppose random variables are sampled from a Gaussian distribution, $Z \sim N (0, 1)$, and each value then multiplied by either $+1$ or $-1$ each with a probability of 0.5.  Is the resulting distribution normal?"  Clear, grammatical, unambiguous even to those who don't have reputations of 100000, and showing the poser cares enough to help potential solvers.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork : There's no need to speak of more than one $Z$ getting sampled and referring to "each" value (as if there's more than one); a single observation was enough.

Comment: I urge you to bring that kind of care to the original poser... the person asking for help.

Answer (score 3):

It is normal.
\begin{align}
\Pr(W\le w) & = \Pr(W\le w\mid\text{heads})\Pr(\text{heads}) + \Pr(W\le w\mid\text{tails})\Pr(\text{tails}) \\[8pt]
& = \Pr(W\le w\mid\text{heads})\Pr(\text{heads}) + \Pr(Z\ge -w \mid \text{tails}) \Pr(\text{tails}) \\[8pt]
& = \Phi(w)\cdot\frac12 + \left(1-\Phi(-w)\right)\cdot\frac12 \\[8pt]
& = \Phi(w)\cdot\frac12 + \Phi(w)\cdot\frac12 \\[8pt]
& = \Phi(w).
\end{align}